# Create cascading dropdownlist that cascades from value but show id

Tags: excel

So i have one sheet in excel where i want a dropdownlist to be cascading from Company and then choose what ever products that is connected to that company name from antoher sheet.

[image]

As you can see on the image. I want Company to be a dropdownlist with different companies. Then i want to be able to press on productcategory and that should also be a dropdownlist and it should cascade from company and give me all the options from the table below what shows products and company and i want it to show me all the products for that specific company. 
How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a three-level dependent data validation scenario. It's a bit of work, but it can be done with named ranges and the Indirect() function.

Debra Dalgliesh has a step by step tutorial here:
http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

If you get stuck, pipe up.